# Listbox value not assigned to variable

Tags: ms-access, listbox, null, vba

I am trying to assign a listbox value to a variable, however every time I run the code I get the Invalid use of Null error.

```
Private Sub CmdEnter_Click()

Dim RS As dao.Recordset
Dim RS2 As dao.Recordset2

Dim FirstName As String
Dim Lastname As String

Dim I As Integer
Dim Department As String


FirstName = TxtFirstName.Value
Lastname = TxtLastName.Value

With LstDepartment

For I = 0 To LstDepartment.ColumnCount
    Department = LstDepartment.Column(I)
Next I

MsgBox Department

End With

'Set RS = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(DBO_UserNamesTbl)

Set RS = db.OpenRecordset("INSERT INTO DBO_UserNamesTbl (UserNo, FirstName, LastName, Department) VALUES (1, Firstname, lastname, department)")

'RS.Execute "INSERT INTO DBO_UserNamesTbl (UserNo, FirstName, LastName, Department) VALUES (1, Firstname, lastname, department)"

Set RS = db.closerecordset(DBO_UserNamesTbl)

End Sub
```

The listbox gets the information from an already created table called departments and it shows and allows me to select the value with no problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to access the "List" property of the ListBox to access its values. Can you please post the code you are using to populate the list box? Then I can give you more details on how to access it.